# How to increase the bar gap in a histogram rowstack style?

Tags: gnuplot

[image]

I want to draw a histogram in the rowstack style. But I don't know how to increase the gap between bars.

I have tried the command:

```
set boxwidth 1.0 absolute
```

But it make the bar smaller. Is there any way to increase the gap between in each bar under the rowstack style or to extend the range of each newhistogram?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by enlarging the size of the terminal.  The gap will be enlarged as the wider size in x-axis.

```
set terminal wxt size 1000,500

set term png size 1000,400
```

Comment: This might work for you if you are flexible with the graph size. However, I would not consider this as a generally satisfying solution, because typically you have a given graph size (and font size) and I would like to increase the gap relative to the graph size.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your gnuplot code, so, it's not (yet) clear to me how exactly you created your clustered *and* rowstacked histogram.
Here is my understanding of gaps in histograms:

- gaps by reduced boxwidth:

  ```
  set boxwidth <myBoxWidth>                 # myBoxWidth < 1.0 to get a gap
  ```
- gaps between clusters by setting cluster gap:

  ```
  set style histogram cluster gap <myGap>   # myGap = integer number, multiple of box space
  ```
- gaps betweeen histograms by setting newhistogram `at`:

  ```
  plot newhistogram "A" at <myGrid> ...     # myGrid = arbitrary value
  ```

  In the example below you have 3 histograms with 4 clusters each. If you want to increase the gap between the 3 histograms, set `myGrid` to something larger then `4`, e.g. `6`.

**Code:**

```
### custom gap setttings in histograms
reset session

$Data <<EOD
One     11   12   13   14   15
Two     21   22   23   24   25
Three   31   32   33   34   35
Four    41   42   43   44   45
EOD

set style data histogram
set style fill solid 0.3
set bmargin 3
set key noautotitle
set yrange[0:]

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set title "default gap settings"
    set style histogram cluster
    plot newhistogram "A" offset 0,-0.7, for [COL=2:4] $Data u COL:xtic(1), \
         newhistogram "B" offset 0,-0.7, for [COL=3:5] $Data u COL:xtic(1), \
         newhistogram "C" offset 0,-0.7, for [COL=4:6] $Data u COL:xtic(1)

    set title "custom gap settings"
    set boxwidth 0.6 relative
    set style histogram cluster gap 0
    myGrid = 6
    plot newhistogram "A" offset 0,-0.7 at myGrid*0, for [COL=2:4] $Data u COL:xtic(1), \
         newhistogram "B" offset 0,-0.7 at myGrid*1, for [COL=3:5] $Data u COL:xtic(1), \
         newhistogram "C" offset 0,-0.7 at myGrid*2, for [COL=4:6] $Data u COL:xtic(1)

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]